# Have multiple routers in different networks being able to view and access each other

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

we have a set up with almost 100 devices, it used to work fine some months ago when we had fewer, but now our main router constantly crashes because it just can't handle so much.

We had 8 routers set as access points and one main router as DHCP server, this set up doesn't work anymore, as such we decided to set another router as DHPC server in an specific section of the building, connected through the WAN port to the first router, and everything is working far better than ever.

Now, to do this we kept the main router network as 192.168.0.1 and we set the second one as 192.168.1.1, however, with this configuration devices can't interact with each other if they are in different networks.
We need all devices to be able to interact with each other regardless of which network they are in.

We plan on setting more routers as DHCP servers for each section of our business as it really seems to improve stability and speed.

Comment: Define "interact". What do those devices require – just ordinary TCP/IP connections? do they rely on broadcast IP packets for discovery? do they need multicast IP? or do they even use some non-IP protocol?

Comment: Being able to fully use shared folders through windows explorer

Comment: Do you need the ability to list (discover) all the computers, or is it enough to directly access specific shared folders through a shortcut (`\\somepc\folder`)?

Comment: Any of the two will do

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://superuser.com/questions/131227/how-do-the-routers-communicate-with-each-other

Comment: A good read but doesn't seem to be related at all

Answer (score 1):

You just need to tell your systems that the network is 192.168.0.0/16.  On Linux, eg.:

```
route add -net 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev eth0
```

Comment: According to OP's description, the two subnets are physically separate due to the way they re-connected the second router – they're not just two addreso ss ranges on the same broadcast domain anymore, so there's no use in telling the OS that the other network is on-link when it isn't.

Comment: I didn't interpret his description as you do.

Comment: @user1686: The WAN connection created a physical sub-segment to the main router. The problem is just that there is no route between `192.168.0.x` and `192.168.1.x`. I would have answered the same. +1

Comment: @harrymc: While it is true that a route is missing, the route also needs to be correct – an on-link route makes no sense precisely _because_ it's a separate "sub-segment" as you say; it needs to have a gateway specified.

Comment: @user1686: I would understand your comment to say that with on-link (directly accessible), all the 100+ computers would be on the same network and will all get all packets, which might cause congestion. Yes, when the poster expands to that stage, he will need to segment and use gateways, which will complicate his network administration. The price of success.

Comment: @harrymc: No, that is not what I'm saying _at all._ I almost feel like you're deliberately misunderstanding me. We're talking in circles.

Comment: We are using Windows in our computers, we want to be able to fully utilize shared folders

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do what I wanted, it was quite easy and still works with Windows 10

[https://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/2013/02/18/windows-task-sharing-files-across-different-subnets/](https://www.npcglib.org/%7Estathis/blog/2013/02/18/windows-task-sharing-files-across-different-subnets/)

Comment: Is this the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the 2nd router does not have NAT enabled.
Then configure the gateway router to NAT for both networks.